# Batch - How To Run Two Commands At The Same Time?

Tags: batch-file

I think someone asked a similar questions ,but mine is a bit different. I have this code:

```
@echo off
title Game
set time=1 am
timeout 10 /nobreak >nul & goto game
set time=2 am
:game
```

How can I make the

```
timeout 5 /nobreak >nul
```

and

```
goto game
```

work at the same time? This is how I want it to work if you still didn't get it:
The timeout starts and you play the game after the timeout ends it changes the time to 2 am. How can I do that at the same time and play the game without getting disturbed? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of the timeout if you aren't delaying the script?

Comment: don't mess with the system variable `%time%`. `1 am` is definitively not a valid value.

Comment: It is a valid value. I tried, except that the time didn't work.

Comment: ugh - yes, you *can* set `%time%` to *any* value, but you *shouldn't*, because then, your time doesn't work anymore...

Comment: lol you dont get it... change the time to var.

Comment: If you want that _"A variable change its value when the game playing time reaches 10 seconds"_, then you must check the playing time inside the game (that should have a loop, so the playing time could be tested in each iteration) and change the variable value at the proper time. There is no other way to do so...

Comment: then you should use a proper time format. `1 am` surely isn't. Even if you set it to a proper format, time wouldn't continue to run, because you set it to a fixed value. To change the system time (I repeat: **you shouldn't!**), use the [time](https://ss64.com/nt/time.html) command: `echo 12:00|time`

Comment: ahem - `time` is more intelligent than I thought: `time 12:00` is the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i *think* you are looking for a "game time", running faster than real time.

Best way: use another script to set a gametime variable (like below) in a separate (minimized) window. Whenever you need to access the current "gametime" in your main script, use `<gametime.dat set /p "gametime="`

GAMETIME.BAT:

```
@echo off
set gametime=10:00
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%gametime%") do (
  set hours=%%a
  set mins=%%b
)
:loop
call :increase_gametime
timeout 5 >nul
goto :loop

:increase_gametime
 set /a mins+=10
 set /a hours=hours+mins/60
 set /a mins=mins%%60
 set gametime=%hours%:%mins% 
 title %gametime%
>gametime.dat echo %hours%:%mins%
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Bob. 'tis you who doesn't get the point about the variable `time`. It is a reserved variable which is set by the system, but can be overridden by a user script. Virtually any other variable name, you can use - just not `time`, `date`, `path`, `random` and a few others.

As to your problem,

```
set "mytime=1 am"
call :starttimer
:game
... whatever

:getinput
set "response="
set /p "response=%~1"
if not exist timerfinished.txt goto :eof
:: here change "mytime"
set "mytime=2 am"
:starttimer
start /min "" timer.bat 10
goto :eof
```

where `timer.bat` is

```
@echo off
del timerfinished.txt 2>nul
timeout %1 /nobreak>nul
echo.>timerfinished.txt
exit
```

The `timer.bat` file simply deletes the flag-file `timerfinished.txt`, delays for the time set by the first parameter it receives (`%1` - set to 10 in main code) then creates the file and exits.

The main code starts the timer initially using `:starttimer` then whenever you want to prompt-and-wait-for-a-response, you execute

```
call :getinput "Prompt for input "
```

and the response will appear in `%response%`.

Note that setting `response` to *nothing* initially in this routine ensures that the response is empty if the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>

OK - so nothing actually *happens* using this scheme until you enter a response, only then will the time be incremented and the game continues with an updated time. If you're expecting that the end of the timeout actually does something, really - that's not going to happen - unless you use `choice` to input your responses with the timeout option.

Comment: I Ment game time not real time :)